# Python pull individual strings when reading a file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am brand new to Python.  I am working through an example on reading files and I've been looking at this for a while and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. What I am trying to do is follow the same logic as if I were searching for a string from a source file to see if it exists in a destination file.  Think of it a my source file being the string dictionary and the destination file being the data file that the strings will be searched for.  That seems to be working, but what I now want to do is pass each of the strings one at a time to a custom module called diff to compare those strings.  What is happening now is that it's throwing the results off because i'm passing a list of strings instead of one at a time. How do I pass the strings one at a time to my diff command below.

```
with open('./dic') as f:
    dictionary = f.read()

if not dictionary:
    sys.exit("Could not read dictionary data :-(")

with open('./dat') as f:
    for dataFile in (line.strip() for line in f):
        print 'dataFile: ', dataFile
        print 'dictionary: ', dictionary
        score=diff.dataL(dataFile, dictionary)
        print 'Diff score: ', score
```

For example my output looks like this - as you can see it's passing 3 items every time for dictionary instead of 1.

```
dataFile:  aaaa
dictionary:  aaaa
bbbb
cccc

dataFile:  test test
dictionary:  aaaa
bbbb
cccc

dataFile:  fail fail
dictionary:  aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `diff` imported from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable dictionary is actually a String, so it is technically one item.  If you want to make it a list, for example to iterate over, you can do this:

```
dictionary_list = dictionary.split()
```

This will make every string separated by whitespace in the String dictionary into an item in the list dictionary_list.

Comment: You're right -- the "three items" he's seeing printed for dictionary is merely one string complete with its `\n`s.

Answer (score 0):

For this line:

```
dictionary = f.read()
```

You want to use the [readlines method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) that returns all lines in a list

Not the [read method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) that returns all the file content in a string